# Why my SVG icon is not displayed in vertical center after using rule "vertical-align: middle"?

Tags: html, css, svg, vertical-alignment

I use the following rule to align a SVG icon in the vertical center:

```
.ssbp-list li a svg {
    line-height: 36px!important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

However, the actual Icon is still in the top, not in the center, why?

Full snippet:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg)
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
        transform:rotate(0)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg)
    }
}
.ssbp-btn:before,
.ssbp-toggle-switch:before {
    display:none;
    font-family:ssbp;
    speak:none;
    font-size:18px;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    font-variant:normal;
    text-transform:none
}
.ssbp-yummly:before {
    content:"\e60b"
}
.ssbp-diggit:before {
    content:"\e60c"
}
.ssbp-twitter:before {
    content:"\e605"
}
.ssbp-reddit:before {
    content:"\e606"
}
.ssbp-tumblr:before {
    content:"\e608"
}
.ssbp-linkedin:before {
    content:"\e609"
}
.ssbp-xing:before {
    content:"\e610"
}
.ssbp-facebook:before {
    content:"\e60e"
}
.ssbp-vk:before {
    content:"\e600"
}
.ssbp-stumbleupon:before {
    content:"\e601"
}
.ssbp-pinterest:before {
    content:"\e603"
}
@media print {
    .ssbp-wrap {
        display:none!important
    }
}
.ssbp-wrap *,.ssbp-wrap :after,.ssbp-wrap :before {
    box-sizing:border-box
}
.ssba-hide-button
.ssbp-each-share,
.ssbp-input-url-div,
.ssbp-text,
.ssbp-toggle-switch,
.ssbp-total-shares {
    display:none
}
.ssbp-wrap {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    font-size:0;
    color:#272727;
    width:100%
}
.ssbp-wrap .ssbp-list {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.ssbp-wrap .ssbp-list li {
    margin-top:1rem;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top
}
.ssbp-wrap .ssbp-list li:first-of-type {
    margin-left:0
}
.ssbp-wrap .ssbp-btn {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:sans-serif
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple-out {
    100% {
        visibility:visible;
        top:-1em;
        right:-1em;
        bottom:-1em;
        left:-1em;
        opacity:0
    }
}
@keyframes ripple-out {
    100% {
        visibility:visible;
        top:-1em;
        right:-1em;
        bottom:-1em;
        left:-1em;
        opacity:0
    }
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-list li {
    margin-left:12px
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn {
    width:3em;
    height:3em;
    line-height:3em;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-transition:.25s;
    transition:.25s
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:hover {
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:10
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:visited {
    color:#fff
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:before {
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .25s;
    transition:transform .25s
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:active:before {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2)
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:after {
    content:'';
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    top:-1px;
    right:-1px;
    bottom:-1px;
    left:-1px;
    pointer-events:none;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.5s;
    animation-duration:.5s
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:hover:after {
    -webkit-animation-name:ripple-out;
    animation-name:ripple-out
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-diggit {
    background-color:#14589e
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-diggit:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-diggit:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-diggit:hover {
    color:#14589e;
    border-color:#14589e
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-facebook {
    background-color:#3b5998
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-facebook:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-facebook:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-facebook:hover {
    color:#3b5998;
    border-color:#3b5998
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-linkedin {
    background-color:#007bb6
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-linkedin:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-linkedin:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-linkedin:hover {
    color:#007bb6;
    border-color:#007bb6
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-pinterest {
    background-color:#ce1a19
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-pinterest:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-pinterest:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-pinterest:hover {
    color:#ce1a19;
    border-color:#ce1a19
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-reddit {
    background-color:#ff4500
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-reddit:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-reddit:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-reddit:hover {
    color:#ff4500;
    border-color:#ff4500
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-stumbleupon {
    background-color:#eb4924
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-stumbleupon:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-stumbleupon:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-stumbleupon:hover {
    color:#eb4924;
    border-color:#eb4924
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-tumblr {
    background-color:#2c4762
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-tumblr:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-tumblr:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-tumblr:hover {
    color:#2c4762;
    border-color:#2c4762
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-twitter {
    background-color:#00a9f1
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-twitter:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-twitter:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-twitter:hover {
    color:#00a9f1;
    border-color:#00a9f1
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-vk {
    background-color:#45668e
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-vk:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-vk:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-vk:hover {
    color:#45668e;
    border-color:#45668e
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-yummly {
    background-color:#e16120
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-yummly:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-yummly:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-yummly:hover {
    color:#e16120;
    border-color:#e16120
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-xing {
    background-color:#026466
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-xing:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-xing:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-xing:hover {
    color:#026466;
    border-color:#026466
}

.ssba img
{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    display: inline !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-sizing: unset;
}
.ssba-classic-2 .ssbp-text {
    display: none!important;
}
.ssbp-list li a {
    height: 36px!important;
    width: 36px!important;
}
.ssbp-list li a:hover {
}
.ssbp-list li a::before {
    line-height: 36px!important;
    ;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.ssbp-list li a:hover::before {
}
.ssbp-list li {
    margin-left: 20px!important;
}
.ssba-share-text {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: inherit;
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list {
    max-width: 48px!important;
    ;
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li a {
    height: 48px!important;
    width: 48px!important;
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li a:hover {
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li a::before {
    line-height: 48px!important;
    ;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li a:hover::before {
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li {
    margin: 0px 0!important;
}
@media only screen and ( max-width: 750px ) {
    #ssba-bar-2 {
        display: block;
    }
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ssbp';
    src:url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.eot?xj3ol1');
    src:url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.eot?#iefixxj3ol1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.woff?xj3ol1') format('woff'),
    url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.ttf?xj3ol1') format('truetype'),
    url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.svg?xj3ol1#ssbp') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: inherit;
    height: 1em;
    overflow: visible;
    /*vertical-align: -.125em;*/
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-10 {
    width: .625em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-14 {
    width: .875em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-16 {
    width: 1em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-18 {
    width: 1.125em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-20 {
    width: 1.25em;
}

svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}

.ssbp-list li a svg {
    line-height: 36px!important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ssba-modern-2 ssba ssbp-wrap left ssbp--theme-1">
    <div style="text-align:left">
        <ul class="ssbp-list">
            <li class="ssbp-li--facebook">
                <a data-site="" class="ssba_facebook_share ssbp-facebook ssbp-btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sybase-recovery.com%2Fblogs%2Fdatanumen-archive-repair-3-8-is-released-on-may-16-2021%2F" target="_blank">
            <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10" id="facebook-f" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
    <path d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z"></path>
  </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edited: Please do not link out to a JSFiddle - include the full minimal viable test case in your questions.

Comment: @MichaelMullany, Thank you very much. I will follow your instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertical-align specified in .my-svg-inline--fa -> which is {vertical-align: -.125em;} is higher priority than the vertical-align specified in .ssbp-list (because it's specified on the class rather than the element.)

Update:

After looking at this more (the CSS here is difficult to follow - with multiple over-rides for the same element and a few too many importants) - this seems to be caused by the computed font-size for its container "a" element being set to zero (inherited from the ssbp-wrap class on the outer container div).

Vertical-align aligns an element relative to where an inline text character would be rendered given the computed font-size, line-height, padding and margin in effect for the container element. With a zero font-size, all vertical-align settings are going to stick that SVG to the top of its container.

You can hack a fix here by adding an explicit font size to the a element containing the SVG. `style="font-size: 11px;"` seems to work fine.

(This CSS could do with a thorough refactor - it's quite confusing - I used an inline style as a quick patch because there are so many clashing/over-ridden declarations in the CSS.)

Full snippet:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg)
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(0);
        transform:rotate(0)
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform:rotate(360deg)
    }
}
.ssbp-btn:before,
.ssbp-toggle-switch:before {
    display:none;
    font-family:ssbp;
    speak:none;
    font-size:18px;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:400;
    font-variant:normal;
    text-transform:none
}
.ssbp-yummly:before {
    content:"\e60b"
}
.ssbp-diggit:before {
    content:"\e60c"
}
.ssbp-twitter:before {
    content:"\e605"
}
.ssbp-reddit:before {
    content:"\e606"
}
.ssbp-tumblr:before {
    content:"\e608"
}
.ssbp-linkedin:before {
    content:"\e609"
}
.ssbp-xing:before {
    content:"\e610"
}
.ssbp-facebook:before {
    content:"\e60e"
}
.ssbp-vk:before {
    content:"\e600"
}
.ssbp-stumbleupon:before {
    content:"\e601"
}
.ssbp-pinterest:before {
    content:"\e603"
}
@media print {
    .ssbp-wrap {
        display:none!important
    }
}
.ssbp-wrap *,.ssbp-wrap :after,.ssbp-wrap :before {
    box-sizing:border-box
}
.ssba-hide-button
.ssbp-each-share,
.ssbp-input-url-div,
.ssbp-text,
.ssbp-toggle-switch,
.ssbp-total-shares {
    display:none
}
.ssbp-wrap {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    font-size:0;
    color:#272727;
    width:100%
}
.ssbp-wrap .ssbp-list {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
.ssbp-wrap .ssbp-list li {
    margin-top:1rem;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top
}
.ssbp-wrap .ssbp-list li:first-of-type {
    margin-left:0
}
.ssbp-wrap .ssbp-btn {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:sans-serif
}
@-webkit-keyframes ripple-out {
    100% {
        visibility:visible;
        top:-1em;
        right:-1em;
        bottom:-1em;
        left:-1em;
        opacity:0
    }
}
@keyframes ripple-out {
    100% {
        visibility:visible;
        top:-1em;
        right:-1em;
        bottom:-1em;
        left:-1em;
        opacity:0
    }
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-list li {
    margin-left:12px
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn {
    width:3em;
    height:3em;
    line-height:3em;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%;
    color:#fff;
    -webkit-transition:.25s;
    transition:.25s
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:hover {
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index:10
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:visited {
    color:#fff
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:before {
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .25s;
    transition:transform .25s
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:active:before {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2)
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:after {
    content:'';
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    top:-1px;
    right:-1px;
    bottom:-1px;
    left:-1px;
    pointer-events:none;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.5s;
    animation-duration:.5s
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-btn:hover:after {
    -webkit-animation-name:ripple-out;
    animation-name:ripple-out
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-diggit {
    background-color:#14589e
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-diggit:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-diggit:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-diggit:hover {
    color:#14589e;
    border-color:#14589e
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-facebook {
    background-color:#3b5998
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-facebook:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-facebook:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-facebook:hover {
    color:#3b5998;
    border-color:#3b5998
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-linkedin {
    background-color:#007bb6
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-linkedin:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-linkedin:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-linkedin:hover {
    color:#007bb6;
    border-color:#007bb6
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-pinterest {
    background-color:#ce1a19
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-pinterest:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-pinterest:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-pinterest:hover {
    color:#ce1a19;
    border-color:#ce1a19
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-reddit {
    background-color:#ff4500
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-reddit:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-reddit:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-reddit:hover {
    color:#ff4500;
    border-color:#ff4500
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-stumbleupon {
    background-color:#eb4924
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-stumbleupon:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-stumbleupon:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-stumbleupon:hover {
    color:#eb4924;
    border-color:#eb4924
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-tumblr {
    background-color:#2c4762
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-tumblr:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-tumblr:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-tumblr:hover {
    color:#2c4762;
    border-color:#2c4762
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-twitter {
    background-color:#00a9f1
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-twitter:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-twitter:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-twitter:hover {
    color:#00a9f1;
    border-color:#00a9f1
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-vk {
    background-color:#45668e
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-vk:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-vk:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-vk:hover {
    color:#45668e;
    border-color:#45668e
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-yummly {
    background-color:#e16120
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-yummly:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-yummly:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-yummly:hover {
    color:#e16120;
    border-color:#e16120
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-xing {
    background-color:#026466
}
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-xing:active,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-xing:focus,
.ssbp--theme-1 .ssbp-xing:hover {
    color:#026466;
    border-color:#026466
}

.ssba img
{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    display: inline !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    box-sizing: unset;
}
.ssba-classic-2 .ssbp-text {
    display: none!important;
}
.ssbp-list li a {
    height: 36px!important;
    width: 36px!important;
}
.ssbp-list li a:hover {
}
.ssbp-list li a::before {
    line-height: 36px!important;
    ;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.ssbp-list li a:hover::before {
}
.ssbp-list li {
    margin-left: 20px!important;
}
.ssba-share-text {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: inherit;
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list {
    max-width: 48px!important;
    ;
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li a {
    height: 48px!important;
    width: 48px!important;
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li a:hover {
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li a::before {
    line-height: 48px!important;
    ;
    font-size: 18px;
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li a:hover::before {
}
#ssba-bar-2 .ssbp-bar-list li {
    margin: 0px 0!important;
}
@media only screen and ( max-width: 750px ) {
    #ssba-bar-2 {
        display: block;
    }
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ssbp';
    src:url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.eot?xj3ol1');
    src:url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.eot?#iefixxj3ol1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.woff?xj3ol1') format('woff'),
    url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.ttf?xj3ol1') format('truetype'),
    url('https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/fonts/ssbp.svg?xj3ol1#ssbp') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: inherit;
    height: 1em;
    overflow: visible;
    /*vertical-align: -.125em;*/
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-10 {
    width: .625em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-14 {
    width: .875em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-16 {
    width: 1em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-18 {
    width: 1.125em;
}

.my-svg-inline--fa.my-fa-w-20 {
    width: 1.25em;
}

svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}

.ssbp-list li a svg {
    line-height: 36px!important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ssba-modern-2 ssba ssbp-wrap left ssbp--theme-1">
    <div style="text-align:left">
        <ul class="ssbp-list">
            <li class="ssbp-li--facebook">
                <a data-site="" class="ssba_facebook_share ssbp-facebook ssbp-btn" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sybase-recovery.com%2Fblogs%2Fdatanumen-archive-repair-3-8-is-released-on-may-16-2021%2F" target="_blank" style="font-size: 11px;" >
            <svg class="my-svg-inline--fa my-fa-w-10" id="facebook-f" viewBox="0 0 320 512">
    <path d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z"></path>
  </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have commented out vertical-align: -.125em; in my original post, but still not work, why?

Comment: Added an update with a full diagnosis and a fix

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works. One more question is how to know the font size should be set to 11px? Just by testing? Is there any good ways to do that?

Comment: There's no easy way to do it - you could create your own font size <-> pixel lookup table and then do a bounding box query on the SVG element to see what to set the font size to. Personally, I would do the whole logo in SVG.   BTW -  If this worked for you - please accept the answer

Comment: Sure. Thank you very much!